# How can the client force the browser to reload cache only for errors like 429?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm accessing servers that are not under my control. They direct the browser to cache responses. I know I can override this with `fetch(url, { cache: "reload" })`, but is there a way to only reload requests known to have failed? I want to use the cache if a successful non-stale response exists, and always reload for unsuccessful responses.

I was surprised to discover that 429's are cached. I'd also like to learn the reasoning behind that.

EDIT: The server sets Cache-Control to an hour, whereas the cause of the 429's resets every minute. So the cache is held for too long in the case of errors. Also, supplying different credentials via an Authorization header does not invalidate the cache.

Comment: HTTP 429 is _"Too Many Requests"_ - allowing caching of that response means fewer requests overall will be made to the overloaded server - why wouldn't you want that? (I assume that excessive request numbers will be coming from software written by people that don't-know-what-they're-doing, so it makes sense to *rely* on deeper knowledge than those-that-didnt-rtfm (i.e. knowledge of caching directives) to "workaround" the 429 error.

Comment: _"but is there a way to only reload requests known to have failed?"_ - the term "failed request" is not well-defined - while obviously a network-error or HTTP 5xx response is a failed-request, I wouldn't consider a HTTP 400 or any other cached response to be a "failed" response.

Comment: @Dai The server sets Cache-Control to an hour, whereas the requests would succeed (no more 429's) after one minute. So the cache is held for too long in the case of errors. Also, supplying different credentials via an Authorization header does not invalidate the cache. Therefore, the behavior is unexpected.